# Are there tests of suggested edits which should be approved?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I am fairly new to reviewing suggested edits (as you can see in the picture), and I have noticed the existance of fake suggestions, which are used as tests to avoid users blindly approve them.

[image: Fake suggested edit]

However, all these tests I have found are edits that should be rejected, but are there tests of suggested edits which should be approved?

I am asking this because I maybe tend to consider too many suggestions as minor edits, and when I check the status of some of them, they have been approved by users with more experience in reviewing. I don't know if for users like me who aren't used to this system it could be useful to have this "good examples" that shouldn't be rejected as a reference.

I also know that if the edit is correct, more users will approve them and these rejects won't have too much repercussion, but I think the earlier we learn how to distinguish between minor and good enough suggestions, the better is going to work the reviewing queue.

Comment: The problem is with people auto-approving everything, so no, there are no audits that require an approve.

Comment: These audits are not acting as guide to train reviewers but rather as "honeypot" to catch those who don't pay attention at all.

Comment: By the way, keep rejecting as too minor if *you think* it is too minor.

Comment: Actually, it should only be rejected as too minor if they missed other stuff that needed editing.  If it only needed one minor edit, then let it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no audits that should be approved (so far).

The goal is to let people know that they're doing it wrong, and hopefully get them to pay more attention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I asked this mainly focused on being less exigent with the suggestions, even though I know the common complaint is exactly the opposite.